# Customize WordPress WooCommerce categories and tags title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress based website with the WooCommerce plugin installed.

On the single product pages, there is the product description, product images, as well as the categories and tags the item is listed under.

How can I change the 'Categories' and 'Tags' title/text to display as something else?

For example, change 'Categories' to 'State' and 'Tags' to 'Suburb'?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be changed in the `/single-product/meta.php` template. You can view the source [on GitHub](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/meta.php).

For more information about overriding default templates, you'll want to read [the WooCommerce docs on overriding template files](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Answer (score 1):

for quick rename anything in woo:

```
add_filter('gettext',  'translate_text');
add_filter('ngettext',  'translate_text');
function translate_text($translated) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Choose and option',  'Select',  $translated);
    return $translated;
}
```